# jQuery Script, Animate() increase the size of an image

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate, image-size

Im running a jQuery Script, Animate()...I want to increase the size of the image when I press the button, how can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      left: '+=250px',
      height: '+=20px',
      width: '+=20px'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div style="position:absolute;">
  <img src="Resources/pez.jpg" height="20" />
</div>
```

if I dont set the height, the image is too big, but this may cause a problem with the script, the image only move to the left, but doesnt increase in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the animate() on the div, you will need to set your `img` to be `100%` of the container `div`, try with CSS:

```
div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Check this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      left: '+=25px',
      height: '+=20px',
      width: '+=20px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div style="position:absolute;">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the height of the DIV around the image, not the image itself.

How about you give the image an id:

```
<img src="Resources/pez.jpg" id="pez" height="20" />
```

and then your jquery selector would look like:

```
$("#pez").animate.....
```